# Check all input Form Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to check if all of my inputs arn't empty.
But my javascript code doesnt check all, just the first one

```
function verif() {

    var noError = true;

    var infos = [
         //{f:name_field,l:length_min,e:error_nb,b:!isNan}
         {f:'nom',l:2,e:"1",b:false},
         {f:'nom_nais',l:2,e:"2",b:false},
         {f:'prenom',l:2,e:"3",b:false},
         {f:'nais',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais1',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais2',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais3',l:4,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:"pays",l:2,e:"6",b:false},
         {f:"tel",l:2,e:"7",b:true},
         {f:"tel_vac",l:2,e:"9",b:true},
         {f:"tel_pers",l:2,e:"11",b:true},
         {f:"previent",l:2,e:"10",b:false},
         {f:"adre1",l:2,e:"5",b:false},
         {f:"adre2",l:2,e:"55",b:false},
         {f:"cp",l:2,e:"13",b:false},
         {f:"ville",l:2,e:"14",b:false},
         {f:"adre1_vac",l:2,e:"8",b:false},
         {f:"adre2_vac",l:2,e:"88",b:false},
         {f:"cp_vac",l:2,e:"23",b:false},
         {f:"ville_vac",l:2,e:"24",b:false}
    ];

    infos.forEach(
        function(item){
            if(item.b){
                if (document.getElementById(item.f).value.length<l || !isNaN(document.getElementById(item.f).value))  {

                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).innerHTML="X !";
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).style.color="red";
                    document.getElementById(item.f).style.backgroundColor="#f4a378";
                    document.getElementById(item.f).style.border="2px solid red";
                    noError = false ;

                }else{
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).innerHTML="OK !";
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).style.color="green";
                }
             } else {

                 if (document.getElementById(item.f).value.length<l)  {

                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).innerHTML="X !";
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).style.color="red";
                    document.getElementById(item.f).style.backgroundColor="#f4a378";
                    document.getElementById(item.f).style.border="2px solid red";
                    noError = false ;

                }else{
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).innerHTML="OK !";
                    document.getElementById("error"+item.e).style.color="green";
                }               
            } 
        }
    ) ;

    return noError;

}
```

I try to check all of my input with method like (document.write/console.log).
Personnaly, i think my error is on the "if" conditions but i dont know why this conditions doesnt work....

One of my inputs :

<input type="text" size="60" id="nom" name="nom" class="keyboardInput" lang="fr" />

Comment: Do you see any error in the JavaScript console? I'm guessing you have a `getElementById` returning null.

Comment: add your HTML code too.

Comment: Why not use `jQuery.validations` ? it's more simple and has many functionalities

Comment: Maybe you don't have id-s for input tags?

Comment: `!isNaN` should be `isNaN`.

Comment: Please add your HTML and make this an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: We don't know what NOM* is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using references to the DOM elements you are trying to modify and implement error checking:

```
    function verif() {
        var noError = true
           ,infos = [
         //{f:name_field,l:length_min,e:error_nb,b:!isNan}
         {f:'nom',l:2,e:"1",b:false},
         {f:'nom_nais',l:2,e:"2",b:false},
         {f:'prenom',l:2,e:"3",b:false},
         {f:'nais',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais1',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais2',l:2,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:'nais3',l:4,e:"4",b:true},
         {f:"pays",l:2,e:"6",b:false},
         {f:"tel",l:2,e:"7",b:true},
         {f:"tel_vac",l:2,e:"9",b:true},
         {f:"tel_pers",l:2,e:"11",b:true},
         {f:"previent",l:2,e:"10",b:false},
         {f:"adre1",l:2,e:"5",b:false},
         {f:"adre2",l:2,e:"55",b:false},
         {f:"cp",l:2,e:"13",b:false},
         {f:"ville",l:2,e:"14",b:false},
         {f:"adre1_vac",l:2,e:"8",b:false},
         {f:"adre2_vac",l:2,e:"88",b:false},
         {f:"cp_vac",l:2,e:"23",b:false},
         {f:"ville_vac",l:2,e:"24",b:false}];

        infos.forEach(function(item){
            try{
        //If an error is found on an iteration, stop checking the rest
                if ( !(noError == false 
                    && typeof item.f == "string"
                    && typeof item.e == "string") ) {
        //Shouldn't get here, but check f & e are valid anyway
                    return;
                }
                var f = document.getElementById(item.f);

                if ( !(f != null && typeof f == "object") ) {
        //Item isn't found in DOM, abort!
                    return;
                }
                var e = document.getElementById("error" + item.e);

                if ( !(e != null && typeof e == "object") ) {
        //Item isn't found in DOM, abort!
                    return;
                }
                if(item.b){       
        //What is 'l', not defined in this scope, should this be item.l ?             
                    if ( f.value.length<l || !isNaN(f.value) )  {
                        e.innerHTML = "X !";
                        e.style.color = "red";
                        f.style.backgroundColor = "#f4a378";
                        f.style.border = "2px solid red";                           
                        noError = false;
                    } else {
                        e.innerHTML = "OK !";
                        e.style.color = "green";
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( f.value.length < l )  {
                        e.innerHTML = "X !";
                        e.style.color = "red";
                        f.style.backgroundColor = "#f4a378";
                        f.style.border = "2px solid red";
                        noError = false;
                    } else {
                        e.innerHTML="OK !";
                        e.style.color="green";
                    }               
                } 
            } catch( ex ) {
               alert("Error in loop iterator: " + ex);
            }               
        });
        return noError;
    }
```

In addition, you could also put a try / catch handler into your function called on each loop iteration.

Also and this may be all your problem is, where is 'l' defined ?  Its referenced in the function, but I don't see it anywhere.